# How Do I Make A Secondary Drive Accessible Through The Main Directory Or In A Way Where Programs That Don't Have A Means To Access It In Their System

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, hard-drive, directory, home-directory

I know that title was a bit convoluted, but I am running on 22.04, I have a Samsung M.2 SSD, and Seagate HDD both connected directly to the motherboard. The issue I keep running into is the secondary drive (HDD) that the OS "IS NOT" installed on is only accessible through "Other Locations" under the "Files" program. When I attempt to save a new file to the HDD like lets say in Blender, the "Directories" that are available only go as deep as the folder above "Home". Certain programs like Steam have an option in the settings under storage to add an additional storage device, but in most situations I have run into that isn't the case.

I am brand new to the Linux system, and kind of am learning as I go. Another issue I am running into which I am not sure whether or not may have something to do with some of my current issues, the HDD appears differently in the "Disks" program then the SSD. I formatted the HDD when I first started installing and updating, but it appears to be full even though it allows me to write to the disk, and the disk is brand new.

I have attempted a few different fixes, but I fear I am in a bit over my head the last attempt some how wiped out the "Home" directory and the only thing I could get to run was "Terminal". So I ended up just reinstalling Ubuntu from the boot menu. This is my first custom built PC, and every OS I have run up to this point has been a Windows. The goal was to build a PC for the purpose of running art, modeling, and game engine work. Windows did not fit into that equation.

So like the title says I need a way to make the HDD accessible to all programs, regardless of program configurations.

I included a picture of the "Disks" program if that helps any I have others but I only able to attach one. I assume I am probably doing something wrong. I appreciate any help, because like I said I am learning, and thank you in advance for your effort and consideration.

[image]

Comment: I do not use snaps and am not sure the snap security works with links. Links
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk Never used this: Link using ~/config/users-dirs.dirs
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462851/shared-home-folder-between-2-linux-os-trippled-booted-w-win11

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your issue, but @oldfred mentions *snap* which run in a *confined* environment that do not have full access to your file-system (excluding $HOME, `/mnt/` and `/media/`) which can be used. I use *fstab* or the file-system table to mount a number of devices (local drives + network shares) & with some have two mounts; one for my normal usage (*paths I prefer*) & another for *snap* or *confined* apps; so I'll provide https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home/1184374#1184374 that maybe helpful for clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have gone back and forth with this, trying to do this in "Terminal" and definitely need to learn more about the "Terminal" commands but I may have solved my own problem on accident. So first I am on 22.04 so it may differ for earlier versions, but

First go to your "Home" directory and copy the directory you want to be your access point for the disk

[image]

go into "Disks"

[image]

select the "Disk" you are trying to make accessible through the "Home" directory

[image]

Main click (Left Click for me) on "Additional Partition Options" (the gear Icon next to the start/stop button)

[image]

go to "Edit Mount Options"

[image]

"Paste" the location of the folder in the "Home" directory you want to make the access point

[image]

Verify and restart your PC.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will achieve what you are asking about with the following steps.

1. Create a new folder in your home directory such as “data”.
2. Edit your /etc/fstab file and add an entry to mount your HDD to /home/user/data when the system boots.
3. Having done the above the entire filesystem of the HDD will appear below the data folder in your home directory. Hopefully this is what you want.

There are plenty of guides online describing how to do these steps if you don’t know how. Your fstab entry should be something like

```
/dev/sda   /home/user/data   ext4   defaults   0   0
```

I noticed that your HDD is not partitioned and that the entire device has an ext4 filesystem. This will work but conventionally you would place one or more partitions on the HDD and then add the filesystem. Without a partition the filesystem is at /dev/sda. Most guide’s expect partitions such as /dev/sda1.

Comment: There have been several questions about issues with full drive partitioning. Now would be best time to backup data & partition drive. With a drive that large you may want more than one partition unless for all media of one type. I typically do not fully partition a drive when I first get it.

Comment: So I'm in the process of "formatting" and erasing the HDD, but it's telling me it's going to take four days. It's accessible and usable, but it never says it's completely empty (0.08%). There has to be a faster way.

Comment: How are you trying to do this? You don’t need to erase anything. You need a new GPT partition table and then create whatever partition(s) you want. It should only take a few minutes if not less